# How would you exclude compressing a sub file inside a main file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

```
 @ECHO OFF
 SET hr=%time:~0,2%
 IF %hr% lss 10 SET hr=0%hr:~1,1%


 Set TODAY=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%-%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%
 ECHO.


 ECHO.
```

This would be the folder to exclude"C:\Users\Downloads\back\temp" from compressing

```
 7za.exe a -tzip "C:\Users\Desktop\Downloadbak-%TODAY%.zip" "C:\Users\Downloads\back*" -mx5
 ECHO.

 PAUSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change current folder to the base folder and use `-x` switch:

   ```
   pushd C:\Users\Downloads\back
   7za.exe a -tzip -mx5 -x!temp -x!exclude2 "C:\Users\Desktop\Downloadbak-%TODAY%.zip" *
   popd
   ```
2. Or pipe `dir` output to `find` to exclude the folder name and use the result as a list file for 7zip:

   ```
   pushd C:\Users\Downloads\back
   dir /b /a | findstr /i /v /r /c:"^temp$" >"%temp%\listfile"
   7za.exe a -tzip -mx5 "C:\Users\Desktop\Downloadbak-%TODAY%.zip" @"%temp%\listfile"
   del "%temp%\listfile"
   popd
   ```

Comment: It worked thanks!                                                                                        How can i do it for multiple files or folders?                                                                                   say to exclude:                                                                                                              C:\Users\Downloads\back\temp and C:\Users\Downloads\back\temp2 and C:\Users\Downloads\back\temp3 ?

Comment: Simply add another `-x!` switch for the method 1 or `/c:` for the 2nd method.